# Docker run exits immediately despite --detach, --interactive, --tty, and providing a command

Tags: docker

On a Windows 10 host, Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d, I tried running a docker image with all possible combinations of `--tty`, `--interactive`, and `--detach`, but none of them brings me to a bash prompt, always exiting immediately. `/bin/bash` is present in the image. The Dockerfile is from https://hub.docker.com/r/astj/centos5-vault/dockerfile

I ran:
`docker run <switches> astj/centos5-vault /bin/bash`
where `<switches>` had been exercised with the full set of `-t`, `-i`, `-d` combinations, namely:
`-d`, `-i`, `-t`, `-it`, `-id`, `-td`, `-dit`

In all cases, the container exits immediately.
If I change `/bin/bash` to `ls`, I can see a directory listing. But of course, the container exits immediately as expected. To troubleshoot, I experimented with the following commands, with these results:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|                        Command                        |                             Output                             |
+-------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| docker run astj/centos5-vault /bin/bash               | None. Exits.                                                   |
| docker run -i astj/centos5-vault /bin/bash            | None. Exits.                                                   |
| docker run -it astj/centos5-vault /bin/bash           | None. Exits.                                                   |
| docker run -t astj/centos5-vault /bin/bash            | None. Exits.                                                   |
| docker run -td astj/centos5-vault /bin/bash           | Prints a container hash, then exits                            |
| docker run -id astj/centos5-vault /bin/bash           | Prints a container hash, then exits                            |
| docker run -d astj/centos5-vault /bin/bash            | Prints a container hash, then exits                            |
| docker run -dit astj/centos5-vault /bin/bash          | Prints a container hash, then exits                            |
| docker run -it astj/centos5-vault ls -la /bin/bash    | "-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 768664 Jul 10  2013 /bin/bash". Exits. |
| docker run -it astj/centos5-vault /bin/bash --version | None. Exits.                                                   |
| docker run -it astj/centos5-vault /bin/bash --login   | None. Exits.                                                   |
| docker run -it astj/centos5-vault /bin/uname -r       | "4.19.128-microsoft-standard". Exits.                          |
| docker run astj/centos5-vault whoami                  | "root". Exits.                                                 |
+-------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I tried to troubleshoot but `docker logs <container>` doesn't show a single line of log.

Does anyone know why the `/bin/bash` command still causes the container to exit immediately instead of bringing me to a bash prompt?

Comment: Does the image actually have `/bin/bash`?  (It's not required and many more minimal images won't.)  If you don't have `-d` but do have `-it`, what does it print out?  Can you include your image's Dockerfile and any other source code needed to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: `/bin/bash` is present. Added Dockerfile link, plus the console output from various attempts to troubleshoot the issue, including output from `-it`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the above issue as well, seems the user above also posted this question separately, and found an answer there:
https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-run-exits-immediately-despite-detach-interactive-tty-and-providing-a-command/99444/5

> For anyone finding their way here later, in my configuration mentioned above
> this was an issue specific to Windows environments which was resolved
> with a change in Windows 10 Build 18995.
>
> Steps to resolve:
>
> ```
> Create file : %userprofile%.wslconfig
> Add this two lines :
> [wsl2]
> kernelCommandLine = vsyscall=emulate
> Restart wsl
> wsl --shutdown
> Restart Docker Desktop
> ```
>
> I found the answer here: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4694#issuecomment-556152512
> (Enable vsyscall=emulate in the kernel config to run older base images such as Centos 6)

This worked for me, it seems to only affect certain distributions, for me it was also centos 6